# Network Bonding - ubuntu 20.04 Can't reach the outside world

Tags: networking, network-bonding

I am at wits end.  I am trying to get network bonding to work. I have tried both using netplan config file and doing it manually with ip commands.  Ether way looks like everything is up and working however I can't reach the outside world.  I have the datacenter confirm that the hardware is capable and configured correctly on their end. I am not sure how to diagnose this any further. I have disabled the firewall.  Any suggestions on what to look for next would be greatly appreciated.

I have to put pictures here as my serial concole via ipmi doesn't allow me to copy past my testing results.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the [Online Subnet Calculator](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A) a /31 network is not valid for what you are doing.  /30 would be the lowest (fewest) amount of hosts you could use at 2 hosts.  If I used 126.27.32.83 as an example, it is stating that your network subnet ID is 126.27.32.80 and your broadcast address is 126.27.32.83, so the IP address you have chosen would not work in a /30 network.

Comment: I have used this subnet for 6 months as a single nic interface.  this is what my isp gave me for ip config.

Comment: The only way that IP addressing would work is that you would have to have a direct to your ISP then like your modem being in transparency mode so that it doesn't give out any IP addressing.  And you would have to be directly connected to a device that is connected to the ISP.

Comment: I am in a datacenter and these machines are directly hooked to a switch that provides internet access.

Comment: If it were me, I would dump netplan all together and go with `ifupdown` instead.  That is what I have done as netplan was too flaky for me on my home network with my server running in `balance-alb` bonding.  Plus, I don't like spacing in configurations, and I too work in data centers and the last one I left wouldn't even touch netplan.  But that's my feelings.

Comment: Have you compared your server to any of the other servers connected to that switch to make sure that your configuration is correct?